# expandRow method not working[jqgrid TreeGrid]

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

```
var record = jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid("getRowData",1); 
$("#gridTable").jqGrid('expandRow', record);
```

above code does not work. 
value of record is as below

```
Object {id: "1", isLeaf: "false", stepNo: "1", stepDescription: "Add New Material", expectedResult: ""…}
actualResult :"All OK"
executionTime : "1.587"
expanded : "false"
expectedResult : ""
icon : ""
id : "1"
isLeaf : "false"
level : "0"
loaded : "true"
parent : ""
status :  "Done"
stepDescription : "Add New Material"
stepNo : "1"
```

but when below code is used to expand row it does work...
only difference that I see is some non quoted numeric values.

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#gridTable').jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
$("#gridTable").jqGrid('expandRow', allRowsInGrid[record.id-1]);

Object {id: 1, isLeaf: false, stepNo: 1, stepDescription: "Add New Material", expectedResult: undefined…}
actualResult : "All OK"
executionTime : "1.587"
expanded : false
expectedResult : undefined
icon : undefined
id : 1
isLeaf : false
level : "0"
loaded : true
parent : ""
status : "Done"
stepDescription : "Add New Material"
stepNo : 1
_id_ : "1"
```

I really need to use 1st method and also understand the issue here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the object returned from `getRowData` as the parameter of `expandRow` is wrong. TreeGrid saves the data locally in `data` array. The parameter of `expandRow` should be element from the local `data`. Thus you should fix the code

```
var rowid = "1",
    record = jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid("getRowData", rowid); 
$("#gridTable").jqGrid("expandRow", record);
```

to

```
var rowid = "1",
    record = jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid); 
$("#gridTable").jqGrid("expandRow", record);
```